# input matrix A with added columns which are the columns of $eye(size(A)(1))$ that do not appear in $A$

Tags: matrices, matlab

I want to make Matlab returns the input matrix A with added columns which are the columns of $eye(size(A)(1))$ that do not appear in $A$.

Example:

input$$A = \begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 7 \\ 2 & 0 & 5 & 6\end{matrix}$$

output
$$A = \begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}$$

I tried to put

```
A = input('Matriz A: ')

I = eye(size(A)(1))
m_ = (intersect(I',A','rows'))'
m_(size(I)(1),size(I)(1)) = 0
for i = 1:size(I)(1)
  p = 0
  for j = 1:size(I)(1)
    if I(:,i) != m_(:,j)
      p = p + 1
    end
    if j = size(I) && p == size(I)(1)
      A(:,size(A)(2) + y) = I(:,i)
    end
  end
end
```

But there is something going wrong. What are the modifications I have to do to this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some erros on your code. Notice `size(I)(1)` produces an error and you probably mean `size(I,1)`. Also, the logical comparison `!=` produces an error. The "not equal to" in MATLAB should be `~=`. You also don't need the for loops, as you can accomplish what you are trying with MATLAB builtin functions [intersect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.intersect.html) and [setdiff](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

Doing it step by step, you can use the code:

```
A = [2 0 1 3
    4 1 2 7
    2 0 5 6];
I = eye(size(A,1));

inter=intersect(I',A','rows')'; % get the columns in I that are in A
A = [A setdiff(I',i','rows')'] % concatenates A and the columns in A not in A
```

To get:

```
A =

     2     0     1     3     0     1
     4     1     2     7     0     0
     2     0     5     6     1     0
```